# c# SOAP with service reference is not showing real response

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm creating an UWP app, that needs to connect to asmx service. I've done that by using service reference, which works with [TempConvert](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit) but not with my asmx service

This is how my code looks like

```
HelpdeskSoapClient HPsoapClient = new HelpdeskSoapClient();
getIncInput input = new getIncInput();

input.username = "450";
getIncResponse realresponse;
realresponse= await HPsoapClient.getIncAsync(input);

Debug.Write(realresponse);
```

but response is not an XML file or something else, but "DTS.helpdesk.getIncResponse"
Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

`getIncResponse` is the object that is returned by the service when you make the call.

When you pass `realResponse` into the `Debug.Write`, since it's an object, the base functionality of `ToString()` is called, which unless overridden in the object will return the fully qualified type name - i.e., `DTS.helpdesk.getIncResponse`.

You should be able to access the properties of the object to get the data, similar to how you set the `username` on the `getIncInput` object (`input.username = "450";`).

The temperature conversion service worked because it returns a simple type (`string`), not a complex type (`getIncResponse`).  There is no error here.